# Curvature evaluation possibility/tool in Blender

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, nurbs-surface

Are there any ways to evaluate curve and connection quality (like Curvature Comb Tool)?
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

[image: CURVATURE COMB]

[image: CURVATURE COMB]

Comment: I've been looking for it since 2018 . There is a plugin for Maya: https://www.stepanjirka.com/maya-plugin-curvature-comb/ Can someone implement this in Blender, maybe?

Comment: This might help: https://blend-exchange.com/b/X4Ywbnmd/